# SpringBoot : how to download file from a MicroService that returns a ResponseEntity<Resource>?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to download a File (PDF or Excel) returned by a Spring Boot Micro Service.
So, I have a GWT application (let's call it "A") and a Micro Service.
The problem is : the micro service creates the required file (perfect) but my browser doesn't display the "Save as" popup. Nothing happens.

Here is what I have so far :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/report")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> generateFullReport(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request,
                                                                @RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("output") String output) throws BirtException {
    log.info("Generating full report: " + name + "; format: " + output);
    EnumOutputType format = EnumOutputType.from(output);

    String filePath = birtReportManagerService.generateMainReport(name, format, response, request);
    File file = new File(filePath);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="+file.getName());
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "no-cache");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "0");

    ByteArrayResource resource = null;
    try {
      resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ResponseEntity responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))
        .body(resource);
//    file.delete();
    return responseEntity;
  }
```

And :

```
@Override
  public void generateBirtReport(String reportName, String reportFormat, HashMap<String, String> parameters) {
    logger.debug("Entering REST generateBirtReport {}", reportName+"."+reportFormat);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()){
      multiValueMap.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(URL_GLOBAL_REST + "/v1/reports/report")
        .queryParam("name", reportName)
        .queryParam("output", reportFormat)
        .queryParams(multiValueMap)
        .build()
        .encode()
        .toUri();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<Resource> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Resource.class);
  }
```

I would like to see that dialog box :

[image: I would like to see that dialog box]

Version : SpringBoot : 2.1.5 / Java : 8

Comment: What happens if you directly hit `...../v1/reports/report` from the browser's address bar? Does that prompts for download? or shows the PDF report?

Comment: it's not so clear, what generateBirtReport is stands for. response is just ignored.

Also it's not clear what is purpose of using HttpServletResponse response in your code.

Beside that - generateFullReport looks ok, and should work. 
Just try to remove 
`String filePath = birtReportManagerService.generateMainReport (name, format, response, request);
    File file = new File (filePath); ` 

and use empty ByteArrayResource (new byte [0]) 

if it work - then you will be able to determinate the problem

Comment: @MasterPo : yes, when I directly hit ...../v1/reports/report , it prompts for download

Comment: @Puh : with an empty ByteArrayResource, that still doesn't prompts for download.

Comment: Basically, what I would like to have is a micro service that generates a file (pdf in this case) and a way to get it back from another application. With the browser displaying the "Save as" for download

Comment: sorry, misunderstand. So generateFullReport is in yours microservice, which works fine, and return generated file for http request, and generateBirtReport is in GWT app?

Comment: @Puh : exactly :-) !

Comment: and how gwt should give a download for your client if you just ignote the response from microservice ?)     ResponseEntity<Resource> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, Resource.class);

Comment: you need to create servlet in GWT part, which will process your request for file download, and copy stream from Resource (returned from microservice) to http response

Comment: @Puh : any idea what I should implement ? What should I do with the response in order to have the "Save as" dialog ?
And why is it working when I directly hit the url ...../v1/reports/report ?

Comment: @AdriL. generateBirtReport just didn't do anything except touching your microservice. It just ignored file returned from it. So there is 2 options. both is about opening in browser new window. for the first option you open url of your's microservice, if it's public, for second - your gwt server should act as reverse proxy, and there would be servlet which restream response from microservice